# Server 12.04 Install Monitor Issue

Tags: 12.04, installation, server, monitor

I've decided to convert an old tower PC with 2Ghz Intel Core Duo and 2Gb RAM into a server using Ubuntu 12.04. I'm far from an expert and completely new to the server side of things...

Previously the whole system worked fine but i've been having issues with the feed to my monitor.

I've tried a couple of reinstalls, a couple of resets and even put in a new 2TB HDD last night and did a fresh install onto the new second HDD. The install went well. On the final reboot stage when I remove the CD and press 'continue' the system shuts down prior to the reboot, then sounds like it's rebooting (system beeps etc.) but my monitor feed goes black - no feedback, no CPU/system splach screen... nothing. The monitor shows the 'no signal' message but the VGA cable is connected and tested on my laptop and works fine.

It did this a couple of days ago so I did a reset with the button on the case and then after a couple of goes it worked fine... last night I shutdown to install the new HDD and it wouldn't boot again. I did a fresh install, which went okay, then on reboot... you've guessed it. Nada. Nothing. Zilch. Zip.

Any clues?
I'd like to stay with 12.04 as this is the system I use on my laptop and the LTS side of things appeals.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Iain.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install server version or desktop version?

Have you take out cd/usb when you finished installation? If not, take them out and try again. You may also try bios booting sequence option.

Comment: Server edition. Yes- the CD was taken out after installation.